# Oracle INSERT INTO SELECT(...) DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception behavior

Tags: oracle, exception

I have a stored procedure which looks like this:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO result_table
  (SELECT (...) FROM query_table);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    NULL;
END;
```

I'm doing it in a loop which passes multiple parameters to the SELECT statement and in some cases some of the values might duplicate that is why I have to catch the DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception.

My question is that if the SELECT statement returns more rows and only one from them exists already in *result_table*, f. ex.

```
1 'A'
2 'B'
3 'C'
```

And first row (1 'A') would already be in the table, would other rows which don't exist (second and third from case above) be inserted? Or none of them would be inserted at all?

I'm afraid that none of them would be inserted (and my test case partially confirms that)... If so, what option do I have to achieve desired bahavior? Is there a good way to insert the rows that don't violate the primary key using the construction above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `MERGE` statement. Insert the records if they don't exist and do nothing if they already exist.

http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html

Comment: That is a really helpful answer and it looks like it shold work the way i'd like it to. I'll try it on monday and post the feedback.

Comment: It works, but it works noticeably slower, but in my case it'll do for now.

Comment: On many threads it produces the same errors as my original statement unfortunately. I'll have to go with cursor :/

Comment: What do you mean "many threads"? Do you have multiple sessions inserting at the same time? In that case, you need to have some sort of serialization. One session must finish the insert, only after that the next session can start, and so on. But, this will not scale.

Comment: We have multiple workers running that procedure simultaneously and trying to make that as user-friendly and scalable as possible. But I believe that this task must be fully serialised unfortunately, so that's a bummer.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, if one record violates constraint, none will be inserted. 
I'd do

```
INSERT INTO result_table
(SELECT (...) FROM query_table a WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT NULL FROM result_table b WHERE b.b_unique_key = a.b_unique_key)
)
```

Another option is to use [error logging](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2.php)

```
INSERT INTO result_table
SELECT ... FROM query_table 
LOG ERRORS INTO err$_dest ('INSERT') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Note: you have to create error table prior to run this query.

Comment: But I'm afraid that because of multiple simultaneous transactions there can be a way that this select statement fetches data which could be inserted in other transaction before this insert statement  and that's why it gets this exception. I've already written the SELECT query in a way that it shouldn`t fetch rows that would violate the index. So my hypothetical scenario looks like this: transaction A fetches rows 1,2,3, transaction inserts row 1 fetched before, transaction A tries to insert 3 rows and raises exception because row 1 is already inserted. How could I handle that?

Comment: I thought of maybe adding the same SELECT statement in the exception handler, but this could also raise the DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception. I don't see any good and valid solution here... :/

Comment: @Ziouas: Then I have couple other suggestions. 1. Insert rows individually ( for instance, using cursors ). 2. `LOCK result_table IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE` and then do your insert (beware : nobody else can update/delete/insert row while you holding lock).

Comment: That is not an option unfortunately in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 11g, then you can use the `ignore_row_on_dupkey_index` hint to suppress the errors:

```
create table tab (id integer);

alter table tab add constraint tab_pk primary key (id);

insert into tab
  select rownum from dual connect by level <= 1;

1 rows inserted.
        ID
----------
         1 

SELECT * FROM tab;

insert into tab
  select rownum from dual connect by level <= 3;

SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (CAM_OWNER.TAB_PK) violated

insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(tab, tab_pk) */into tab
  select rownum from dual connect by level <= 3;

SELECT * FROM tab;

2 rows inserted.
        ID
----------
         1 
         2 
         3
```