# Execute immediate ... Catching record specific exception

Tags: exception, plsql, oracle11g, execute-immediate

I am insertin some values in `Table2` from `Table1`. There could be chances that there are Primary Key collision. I am using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to insert value from `Table1` to `Table2`.

The records could be in million and there is only 1 commit i.e.,

```
    execute immediate 'insert into table 2 (select * from table 1)';
    delete from table1;
    commit;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
     ROLLBACK;
     --LOGGING
```

Is there a way that i can log the exact row which caused primary key collision in exception block ?

I know i can use "bulk" insert and "save exception" method but for some complex reasons,I am not allowed to change the script for this thing right now.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Try using the following:  `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQLCODE=' || to_char(SQLCODE) || '  Error=''' || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK || '''  Backtrace=''' || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE || ''''`.

Comment: can you put it as an answer so that i can accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of failing at all you could do a partial insert and capture the errors in an error log as described in the answer to this question

[Oracle INSERT INTO SELECT(...) DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649622/oracle-insert-into-select-dup-val-on-index-exception-behavior)

Also I am not sure why you want to do an `execute immediate`. But maybe above is just an example and you really want to do this dynamically. You can work it out from my experiment:

```
create table table1 (mycolumn varchar2(200));

create table table2 (mycolumn varchar2(200));

exec  DBMS_ERRLOG.create_error_log (dml_table_name => 'table2');

create unique index table2_i1 on  table2 (mycolumn);

insert into table1 values ('one thing');
insert into table1 values ('another thing');
insert into table1 values ('another thing');

INSERT INTO table2
    SELECT * FROM table1 
    LOG ERRORS INTO err$_table2 ('INSERT') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

commit;

select * from err$_table2;

select * from table2;
```

Output

```
table TABLE1 created.
table TABLE2 created.
anonymous block completed
unique index TABLE2_I1 created.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
2 rows inserted.
committed.
ORA_ERR_NUMBER$ ORA_ERR_MESG$  ORA_ERR_ROWID$ ORA_ERR_OPTYP$ ORA_ERR_TAG$ MYCOLUMN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
--------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
          1               ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYS.TABLE2_I1) violated I INSERT another thing                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

MYCOLUMN 
--------------
one thing                                                                                                                                                                                                
another thing
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQLCODE=' || to_char(SQLCODE) ||
                     ' Error=''' || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK ||
                     ''' Backtrace=''' || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE ||
                     '''');
```

Share and enjoy.